# Two idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, idempotents

Let $A,G$ be two $n\times n$ matrix satisfying:
$$A^2=A, GAG=G, im(G)\subset im(A).$$ Prove that $G^2=G$.

I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: check that given $A^2=A$, $\mbox{im} G\subseteq \mbox{im } A $ implies $AG=G\iff (I-A)G=0 $ (that's actually equivalent). Then just compute $G^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$im(G) \subset im(A)$,so for any vector $u$,there is a vector $v$ that

$$Gu=Av$$.

So we get:

$$Gu=GAGu=GAAv=GA^2v=GAv=GGu=G^2u$$

.

QED.